# Angular 6 allowing dots "." in app name

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm just starting a new Angular app that will be part of an Asp.Net WebApi solution that consist of many projects which uses dots in their names like xxxx.Data, xxxx.Common, xxxx.Auth, etc and so I'd like to name the Angular frontend layer, following the same schema so its name should be xxxx.Web but executing ng new xxxx.Web throws an error advising app name is incorrect.

One quick solution I found is to create the app like xxxx-Web and then rename the folder to xxxx.Web and then replace all occurrences of the string in json files recursively and it works just fine but...

Is it safe to do this? Won't bring me problems in the future?
Why ng new doesn't allow dots in app names natively when using a dot is allowed for a folder name in OS?

Thanks.

Comment: whats SO? and why do you _need_ the `.` on it?

Comment: That naming schema for .NET projects usually matches the root namespace of a project. Angular projects are unrelated to your .NET namespaces, so it makes little sense to follow the same schema.

Comment: It's OS (Operating System) @mast3rd3mon, sorry I was thinking in spanish and wrote it the same way. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @Stijn. Maybe you are right but I love uniformity across a whole project in what about naming schema (and other aspects) respects and presentation layer is a part of the whole project, that's why I prefer to follow the same naming convention, but only if I'm not going to came across with problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

@angular/cli doesn't allow naming apps like this. Please read [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3816) for more info on the same.

That being said, you can create your own schematic as a workaround. angular.io has an amazingly enlightening [Medium Article](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2) that you can read about here.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply @Siddharth Ajmera. I don't know why you were downvoted but anyway I will have a look at the article you mention to see if I can find something interesting that helps.

Comment: Schematics is something that can help you develop a custom CLI that fits your needs. In fact, Angular CLI has been built on the top of Angular Schematics itself.

Comment: I'm not marking your answer as the correct because I'm not totally convinced @Siddharth because although Angular cli doesn't allow names with dots in it I was able to rename it after creation and after replaced all occurrences of the old name with the new with dots app started correctly (I have to say I have only tested with the base Angular app cli creates and not with a complex app though).

Comment: I wasn't trying to convince you here. All I was saying is, there's a way to do what you're trying to do without manually changing the App names and its occurrences in your app.

Comment: This is a year late and I just stumbled on this thread.  And regardless of the "correct" answer, @SiddAjmera does a great job of replying with an open mind and trying to understand the original question and Diego's point of view; rather than belittle the question or the approach as the other comments do.  
Well done on contributing to a positive learning environment SiddAjmera.